# Tabla Temporal - Mostrar registros únicos de una columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dentro de un procedimiento almacenado he creado una tabla temporal #Temp_Saldos a la cual le estoy creando nuevos campos que se muestran sin problemas cuando ejecuto el procedimiento almacenado.

[image: Nuevos campos de Tb Temporal]
Ahora, el campo "CltsVcdos" me muestra los Id's de los clientes que tienen deuda vencida. Como un cliente puede tener varios comprobantes vencidos, me muestra los Id's repetidos en muchos casos.

Lo q necesito es mostrar, dentro de la última "CltsVcdosUnicos", los clientes con deuda vencida pero NO REPETIDOS. Una opción es mostrar 1 cuando es cliente único, y 0 cuando es repetido.

[image: Resultado esperado]

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda la opción distinct no es lo correcto en las buenas practicas de hecho en el ambiente de servicios financieros esta prohibido utilizarla, se tiene que utilizar un group by agrupa por cltsvdocs

```
select ctsvdocs, count(ctsvdocsunicos)
from #temp
group by ctsvdocs;
```

en el count te va a sumar el numero de folios que tiene, ya de allí puedes distinguir con un case when si es mayor a 1 o como tu te acomodes, saludos.

Comment: El detalle está en que los campos q se listan en la izquierda del query como "MontoCltsVcdos",  "CltsVcdos", o "CltsVcdosUnicos" son campos TEMPORALES osea q todavía no existen y solo los estoy añadiendo para hacer cálculos. Es por eso q no puedo tomar esos campos para hacer un Group By. Los campos de la derecha como IdClieenteFacturacion, Saldo, y FechaVencimiento si existen y pertenecen a tablas físicas.

Comment: te recomiendo crear una tabla con tus diferentes tipos de atrasos, para que cuando se requiera cambiar los días correspondientes a algún tipo de atraso no tengas ningún problema al hacerlo, una vez que la tengas solo haces el cruze con las de saldos un join y en el on le dejas que tiene que estar entre uno y otro, ya como vas a tener un nombre por cada tipo de atraso, te va a quedar como tu lo requieres para hacer el group by, si se te hace mas fácil, lo puedes mandar a una tabla temporal #temp, para que de allí le hagas el agrupamiento, cualquier cosa por aquí ando, saludos.

Comment: te dejo un ejemplo como lo realizaria con una tabla y el join. https://github.com/angelnmara/consultasSQL/blob/master/carteraVencida.sql

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que se me ocurre que podrias realizar es un Count por medio de una subconsulta + el atributo DISTINCT quien te mostrara el total de clientes vencidos diferentes sin repetir.
Ejemplo subconsulta

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT Cltsvcdos) AS CLTSVcdosUnicos From (tabla)

el resultado se repetira en cada registro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos miguel, esto tiene pinta de comentario, si intentas dar una respuesta, [edita tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/148383/edit) proporcionando una información mas clara, o utiliza la caja de comentarios si solo deseas realizar un comentario.

Comment: Asi es. Me da igual si me muestra un 1 por c/cliente único, o en su defecto q me muestre el id del cliente pero NO REPETIDO.

Comment: avisame si te resuelve la respuesta editada

Comment: El detalle está en que los campos q se listan en la izquierda del query como "MontoCltsVcdos", "CltsVcdos", o "CltsVcdosUnicos" son campos TEMPORALES osea q todavía no existen y solo los estoy añadiendo para hacer cálculos. Es por eso q no me deja hacer un count o distinct con el campo "CltsVcods". Los campos de la derecha como IdClienteFacturacion, Saldo, y FechaVencimiento si existen y pertenecen a tablas físicas.